# IntelliJ IDEA use macros in Working Directory of Run Configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, run-configuration

Coming from Eclipse, I am used to set the base directory of a Maven Run Configuration dynamically by using variables like ${project_loc}. With that, I am able to just select one specific Maven Module (out of >100) and just run the configuration for that specific module.

In IDEA, I cannot find this functionality. The dialog box for setting the working directory of a Maven run configuration does not accept macros - in contrast to for example the dialog box for VM options which has a “insert macros” button.

Is this feature not implemented in IDEA or am I missing something?
Working with Intellij IDEA 2023.1 CE

Thanks, Patrick

Answer (score 0):

According to this forum post, this feature is currently not available but should be included in one of the upcoming releases.
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/14651974051602-use-macros-in-Working-Directory-of-Run-Configuration